# Sybase SQL Anywhere - finding the ancestor via conditional join?

Tags: sql, join, sqlanywhere

In a rather omplex SELECT, I want to find the name of the oldest ancestor for each node in a tree structure. Every node has either one or two generations of ancestors. Their heritage is described in the table Category and their names are found in the table Category_description.

```
Category

cat_id (uniqueidentifier) cat_parent_id (uniqueidentifier)

Category_description

cat_id (uniqueidentifier) cat_description (nvarchar)
```

So, I have already honed in on a specific row in Category via a join (let's call this c). And now what I want to do is something like this, pseudo codedly:

```
IF cat_parent_id = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
   THEN
       SELECT cat_description from Category_description where cat_id in (
       SELECT cat_parent_id from c)
   ELSE
       SELECT cat_description from Category_description where cat_id in (
       SELECT cat_parent_id from Category WHERE cat_id in (
       SELECT cat_parent_id from c)
```

Am I making myself understood here?

Also, would I be best off if I put the conditional in a join?

Comment: Did you solve this problem yet? what version of Sybase are you using?